# eBPF: how to get the socket associated to a sock from a `struct __sk_buff`

Tags: c, linux, sockets, kernel, ebpf

I am currently writing an eBPF program in C to track egress network packets using `tc-bpf`. The program has its definition as follows:

```
SEC("classifier")
int bpf_tc_sample(struct __sk_buff *skb) {
    [...]
    return TC_ACT_OK;
}
```

In my program, I need to get the socket associated with the sock of the socket buffer.
If the type of the socket buffer would have been `struct sk_buff` this could have been done by accessing `skb->sk->sk_socket`. In this case, the type of `skb->sk` is `struct bpf_sock` and not `struct sock` which does not contain an entry for `sk_socket`.

Could anyone please let me know whether there is a way to access the `struct socket` field from a `struct __sk_buff` entry in an eBPF program, either through a BPF helper or via using a `kprobe`.
Any insight will be appreciated.

Comment: This is definitely possible using kprobes instead of tc-bpf. I don't think it's possible directly from a tc-bpf program. However, if you could describe your use case (why do you want sock?), maybe we could help you find a better way?

Comment: @pchaigno The use case of the BPF program I am developing is to track egress IPv4 packets, fetch the corresponding packet data using the socket buffer, and then send it to userspace using the Ring Buffer. Along the packet data, I am also interested to get the socket associated with the sock of the socket buffer corresponding to the outgoing packet detected. I have seen a similar example use case in [tcpdrop](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/tcpdrop.py), although I was wondering if there could be a more general approach to cater for UDP packets as well.